# Print the last-but-one field

Tags: sed, awk, perl, ksh

How to print the word before the last word in line (with ksh or awk or sed or perl one liner)

Example 1:

```
  echo one two three
```

will print "two"

Example 2:

```
 echo 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

will print "5"

Comment: Pure ksh: `n=1 a=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 ) && echo ${a[${#a}-n-2]}`, but the `awk` solution has my preference.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, or `"${a[-2]}"` in `zsh` or recent versions of `ksh93` or `bash` or `"${a[@]: -2:1}"` in older versions of `ksh93` or `bash` (or newer zsh). Note that none of them work for sparse arrays (zsh arrays are never sparse).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

`NF` is the number of fields -- all that happens here is that one is subtracted from the total field length to get the penultimate field.

With perl:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[-2]'
```

An array containing the fields is created as `@F` (that's what `-a` does), and we get the value of the second last field (with index `-2`).

Using sed is slightly less palatable, since it doesn't have any concept of fields. I'd recommend using one of the above, instead.

Comment: Do you confuse when saying arrayref? I think it is just **array**.

Answer (score 3):

I put the below in a subshell so you don't change your current environment too drastically - they're all native shell builtins.

```
(set -f; unset IFS ; set -- ${line}
 shift "$((${#}${2+-2}))" && printf ${2+%s}'\n' "$1")
```

I edited this to disallow globbing - I added `set -f` according to advice offered in the comments below.

Comment: This will fail if your expansion contains globs, among other things.

Comment: What does that mean? Expansion of what, the last word? Oh, you mean pathname expansion. That's a good point. I'll fix it. Thanks, man.

Comment: Your `-f` will apply only once that `set` command is executed, so not for the expansion of `$line` above. You need `set -f; set -- $line`.

Comment: You unset the IFS - some shells will handle that differently than others, right? I remember reading something recently on a mailing list about unspecified behavior if IFS is unset... Or maybe it was \0... Anyway, the check for enough positionals is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`rev | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | rev`

or

`rev | awk '{print $2}' | rev`